# Subscribe Popup plugin on WooCommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, popup, product

Today I was trying to add popup on product page (Wordpress, WooCommerce)

I used two plugins.

One is "Popup by Supsystic" it is showing popup on all pages. (I just want it on product page)

Second is Yith popup (It is showing popup on the pages but it doesn't offer popup on product page)

My question is can someone suggest me a plugin which shows subscription popup on product page only.

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [YITH WooCommerce Popup](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-popup/) (for woocommerce pages only)…

Have also a look to this related post: [How to Use WooCommerce 2.0 Lightbox](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-use-woocommerces-lightbox-part-2/)
It explains how to use native prettyPhoto, a Lightbox implementation…